# Merge same name shapefile of different folders

Tags: shapefile, merge

How to merge shapefiles of same name?

I have 100 folders and each folder has 100 shapefiles with the same name.  I need to merge all "school.shp" of each folder to one shapefile

I'm using ArcGIS 10.5, and I'm new to ArcGIS.

Comment: Should be fairly easy to use gdal and a script. What have you tried?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: Name isn't nearly as important as schema. The files must have the same fields (name, width, and type), or your task is more difficult by an order of magnitude or two. Please specify the GIS software in use and what you have tried. This is a common enough request that this is likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As @Vince said, schema is important.  If the files all identical in terms of schema, than all you need to do is select a target file and [append](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/append.htm) all the rest of them to that file.  Just drag-and-drop the shapefiles into the Input Datasets list.
If your schema are not identical, you can re-map things to the appropriate field.  If they aren't identical—or you don't want to risk errors appearing because ArcGIS *thinks* they're not identical—set the schema type drop-down to "NO_TEST".
If trying to append everything at once gives you an error, especially Error 99999, try appending things in batches.  If this is something you're going to be doing repeatedly, then you might want to look into creating a model to iterate through the files and then append them to a selected target file.